# help understanding a definition in custom class

Tags: macros, document-classes

Can someone help with decoding the code at the bottom?
Note that the code is part of a custom class for dissertation that i found.

Specifically:
`\def\@degreeyear{#1}\if@cyrset\else\def\@copyrightyear{#1}\fi`

1. Can someone explain step by step what this line does?
2. What is the purpose of `\if@cyrset` when this is always be false why
   not just
       `\def\@degreeyear{#1}\def\@copyrightyear{#1}\fi` even though I still
       have no idea what this is supposed to do?
3. Why is `\def\@degreeyear{\number\month}` as month?
4. and why is `\@degreeyear` defined twice? (The author says in a comment that when `\degreeyear` is not used, current year is used. But even if `\def\@degreeyear{\number\year}` was used, I still do not see the conditional logic).
5. In general where does `\def` ends definition (space possibly?)?

The code:

```
\def\@degreeyear{\number\month}
\def\@degreemonth{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi}
\def\@copyrightyear{\number\year}
\newif\if@cyrset
\@cyrsetfalse
\newcommand{\degreeyear}[1]
   {\def\@degreeyear{#1}\if@cyrset\else\def\@copyrightyear{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\degreemonth}[1]{\def\@degreemonth{#1}}
\newcommand{\copyrightyear}[1]{\def\@copyrightyear{#1}\@cyrsettrue}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class defines a default value for `\@degreeyear`, `\@degreemonth` and `\@copyrightyear`. I'm not sure why `\@degreeyear` has `\number\month` instead of the expected `\number\year`, probable oversight.

Then it defines a conditional to distinguish whether the copyright year is being set by the user and proceeds to define user level commands for setting dates.

If the user has

```
\degreeyear{2020}
```

then the macro `\@degreeyear` is defined to expand to `2020`. The value of `\@copyrightyear` is not changed unless `\if@cyrset` is false.

If the user has

```
\copyrightyear{2019}
```

then `\@copyrightyear` is set to 2019 and `\if@cyrset` is set to true.

The `\def` commands inside the replacement text for `\newcommand{\degreeyear}` are not performed when the definition is absorbed, but only when `\degreeyear` is executed.

The effect is that issuing the commands in either order will always do the right thing. Not issuing `\copyrightyear` will set `\@copyrightyear` to the same value as `\@degreeyear`.

Let's see why. At the end of class loading, `\if@cyrset` returns the false branch. I'll assume that at least `\degreeyear{2020}` appears in the document preamble. There are three cases:

1. just `\degreeyear{2020}`
2. `\degreeyear{2020}\copyrightyear{2019}`
3. `\copyrightyear{2020}\degreeyear{2020}`

In the first case `\@degreeyear` and `\@copyrightyear` are both set to 2020.

In the second case, `\degreeyear{2020}` does as in case 1, but the later `\copyrightyear{2019}` command overwrites the value previously assigned to `\@copyrightyear`. The `\@cyrsettrue` bit does nothing.

In the third case, `\@copyrightyear` is set to 2019 and `\if@cyrset` is set to return the true branch. Thus `\degreeyear{2020}` will only set `\@degreeyear` and skip the setting to `\@copyrightyear`.

This is done in order to avoid requiring the user to specify `\degreeyear` and `\copyrightyear` in a particular order. The latter command is optional, because if not given the setting of `\@copyrightyear` will be the same as that of `\@degreeyear`.

The `@`-macros will presumably be used by the class to typeset the title pages.

Comment: So the line `\@cyrsetfalse` is "executed" when the class is loaded, that is before anything else and then if one also has in the preamble `\copyrightyear{2019}` only then `\def\@copyrightyear{#1}\@cyrsettrue` is "executed"?

Comment: @leosenko Yes, at the end of class loading `\if@cyrset` is false. But executing `\copyrightyear` in the preamble sets it to true. I'll add something.